# How to call IEGetProtectedModeCookie API from a high-integrity (admin) process?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, cookies, protected-mode

I need to call the IE8 **IEGetProtectedModeCookie** API from a **high-integrity (admin) process**. Whenever I call this API from my Azure webapp, I'm getting **ERROR_INVALID_ACCESS**. I've read in a number of places that high-integrity processes can't call this API, but in my case I need to run the Azure sandbox with elevated privileges.

Is there any way to call this API from a lower level integrity process? For the Azure sandbox, I'm forced to run my webapp with elevated privileges.

```
  [DllImport("ieframe.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, EntryPoint = "IEGetProtectedModeCookie", SetLastError = true)]
  public static extern int IEGetProtectedModeCookie(String url, String cookieName, StringBuilder cookieData, ref int size, int flag);

  private static string GetProtectedModeIECookieValue(string cookieName)
  {
     String r = String.Empty;

     int iSize = 4096;
     StringBuilder sbValue = new StringBuilder(iSize);

     Uri reqUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
     string baseUrl = String.Format(@"{0}://{1}", reqUri.Scheme, reqUri.Authority);

     int hResult = IEGetProtectedModeCookie(baseUrl, cookieName, sbValue, ref iSize, 0);

     if (hResult == 0)
     {
        string[] parts = sbValue.ToString().Split('=');
        r = parts[1];
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(r);
     }
     else
     {
        //HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("Failed to get cookie. HRESULT=0x" + hResult.ToString("x") + "\nLast Win32Error=" + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());
     }

     return r;
  }
```